# How do I sort my list from my text file into alphabetical order by genre or title?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is my text file

```
#Listing showing sample book details 
#AUTHOR, TITLE, FORMAT, PUBLISHER, COST?, STOCK, GENRE
P.G. Wodehouse, Right Ho Jeeves, hb, Penguin, 10.99, 5, fiction
A. Pais, Subtle is the Lord, pb, OUP, 12.99, 2, biography
A. Calaprice, The Quotable Einstein, pb, PUP, 7.99, 6, science
M. Faraday, The Chemical History of a Candle, pb, Cherokee, 5.99, 1, science
C. Smith, Energy and Empire, hb, CUP, 60, 1, science
J. Herschel, Popular Lectures, hb, CUP, 25, 1, science
C.S. Lewis, The Screwtape Letters, pb, Fount, 6.99, 16, religion
J.R.R. Tolkein, The Hobbit, pb, Harper Collins, 7.99, 12, fiction
C.S. Lewis, The Four Loves, pb, Fount, 6.99, 7, religion
E. Heisenberg, Inner Exile, hb, Birkhauser, 24.95, 1, biography
G.G. Stokes, Natural Theology, hb, Black, 30, 1, religion
```

And this is the code i used to read the text file and stored it in a list
book_list = []

```
def readbook():
    
    infile = open('book_data_file.txt')

    for row in infile:
        start = 0 # used to start at the begginning of each line
        bookrecord = []

        if not(row.startswith('#')):
            for index in range(len(row)):
                if row[index] ==',' or index ==len(row)-1:
                    bookrecord.append(row[start:index])
                    start = index+1
                    
            book_list.append(bookrecord)
    infile.close()
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello Adam! Welcome to SO. Can you please provide [minimal, complete, reproducible example] of your problem? You have showed us your data and the code, but what are you looking to do visually?

Comment: Hey! Thanks man!, My desired output would just be all the rows from the text file printed back to the user(the same way the text file looks) but sorted in alphabetical order and giving an option to sort it by genre or title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

sort by title

```
def sortByTitle():
    data = ''
    title_list = []
    new_data = []
    
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as r:
        data = r.read()
    
    
    title_list = sorted(data.split(', ')[1::7])
    
    i=0
    while len(new_data)!=len(data.split(', '))//7:
        temp_data = data.split(', ')[7*i:7*(i+1)]
        new_data.append(temp_data)
        i+=1
 
    j=0
    while  j<len(title_list):
        
        for i in range(len(new_data)):
            if new_data[i][1] == title_list[j]:
                temp = new_data[j]
                new_data[j]=new_data[i]
                new_data[i] = temp 
                j+=1
            
    
    
    print('Title_list: ', title_list)
    print('Books: ',new_data)
```

Sort by Genre

```
def sortByGenre():
    data = ''
    Genre_list = []
    new_data = []
    
    
    with open('file.txt') as r:
        data = r.read()
    
    
    Genre_list = sorted(data.split(', ')[6::7])
    i = 0
   
    while len(new_data)!=len(data.split(', '))//7:
        temp_data = data.split(', ')[7*i:7*(i+1)]
        new_data.append(temp_data)
        i+=1
    
    j=0
    while  j<len(Genre_list):
        for i in range(len(new_data)):
            if new_data[i][6] == Genre_list[j]:
                temp = new_data[j]
                new_data[j]=new_data[i]
                new_data[i] = temp 
                j+=1

    
    print('Genre: ', Genre_list)
    print('Books: ', new_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('book_data_file.txt' , sep=',' , header=0)
df.sort_values(by=["GENRE"])
df.sort_values(by=["TITLE"])
```

**Notes**

You've left some spaces around the column names in the text file, make sure you remove these and save the text file again before importing, otherwise the column headers will have unnecessary leading spaces such as " GENRE"

**Explanation**

Your text file is formatted like a 'csv' (a comma separated values file), so you can use Pandas' 'read_csv' to load your text file into a Pandas DataFrame. Pandas DataFrames allow you to format data as a table, which then gives you the ability to sort data by any column (as well as endless other manipulations)

This specifies that your values are separated by commas, and therefore need to now be separated at commas:

```
sep=','
```

and this specifies that the first line of the text file holds the column header names:

```
header=0
```

Then you can sort by any column using:

```
df.sort_values(by=["COLUMN_NAME"])
```